# NgModel empty with select html tag

Tags: html, angular, angular-ngmodel, ngfor

Look a this:

```
        <label>Business unit</label>
        <select name="BU" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="interventionForm.DLCODBUN">
            <option *ngFor="let item of buList" >{{item.id}}</option>
        </select>
```

When I open the relative web page, the select box show a default value ( the first of the list ) , but that's only a view binding.

[**here's the image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFJ4h.jpg)

Infact, if i go on with in the application, the variable bound with [(ngModel)] will be undefined.

Only with a selection on the select box interventionForm.DLCODBUN will be populated, but i want the same thing with the default value! 
isn't strange? Someone know a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it caused by missing the ngValue attribute in the option tag.

Try to add item value to the option tag, it may work.

```
<option *ngFor="let item of buList" [ngValue]="item.value">{{item.id}}</option>
```

Comment: "dat do de ting". Thanks XD

Answer (score 2):

Assign interventionForm.DLCODBUN this with the default value in your component.ts . Then it will appear in the select box as well and you will have the value in component.ts . You will not get the assigned value until you change something from drop down , so best option is assign a default value already in the component.ts